# How to import a csv with OpenCSV to FX SimpleObjectProperties?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, javafx, opencsv

For a school assignment, I need to parse a CSV into a Bean and present it in a JavaFX GUI later. I decided to use the Library opencsv, which worked fine.

But now, I would like to parse the attributes directly into SimpleObjectProperties. How do I do that? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any further information.

Code looks like this:

```
public class Phone {

@CsvBindByName(column = "ENTITY_ID")
private SimpleIntegerProperty entityId;

@CsvBindByName(column = "OPERATING_COMPANY")
private SimpleStringProperty operatingCompany;
```

When I run the code, I get a CsvDataTypeMismatchException *(Conversion of 1006 to javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty failed)*.
Any help much appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it looks like you can create CustomConverts for each type of property you have; the example they have on the documentation page, this is the start to an IntegerPropertyConverter.

```
public class IntegerPropertyConverter extends AbstractCsvConverter {

   @Override
   public Object convert(String value) {
       return new SimpleIntegerProperty(Integer.parseInt(value));
   }

   @Override
   public String convertToWrite(Object value) {
       IntegerProprety prop = (IntegerProperty) value;
       return String.format("%d", prop.get());
   }

 }
```

Then you'd use:

```
@CsvCustomBindByName(column = "ENTITY_ID", converter = IntegerPropertyConverter.class)
private SimpleIntegerProperty entityId;
```

If you need to create your properties using the longer format, you will need to override other methods in the AbstractBeanField, such as `public final void setFieldValue(T bean, String value, String header)` where you can actually use the bean to create the

Comment: Thanks that helped. But instead extending from AbstractCsvConverter it needs to be AbstractBeanField.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way around this.

You keep your *Phone* a *POJO* and map the entire object as a property

```
private SimpleObjectProperty<Phone> phone = new SimpleObjectProperty<Phone>();
```

Or you could add properties to the *Phone*

```
public class Phone {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ENTITY_ID")
    private Integer entityId;

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty entityIdProperty;

    public Phone() {
        entityIdProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        entityIdProperty.addListener((o, oldValue,newValue)->{
            entityId = newValue.intValue();
        });
    }

    public Integer getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(Integer entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
        entityIdProperty.set(entityId);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty getEntityIdProperty() {
        return entityIdProperty;
    }


    // ...
}
```

If you do not need this object to have a bidirectional binding you could skip the listener.

There are other possibilities too, like having Methods and constructors to convert from a Phone to a PhoneFX (with properties instead of simple types) and viceversa.